$L=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})$. Find Galois group and all intermediate fields of $L/\mathbb{Q}$
$L=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})$ subfield $\mathbb{C}$ and show that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension. Find the corresponding Galois group and all intermediate fields of $L/\mathbb{Q}$
I show that it is Galois and also got that both $i,\sqrt{2} \in L$ so basically $L=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$. Since the minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ is $x^4+1$, we get $|Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}|=4$ which means $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ or $K_4$.
This is where I am stuck. I thought that I should consider $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ and get two automorphisms with $\sigma(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sigma(i)=i$ with $\tau(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ and $\tau(i)=-i$. Then we get $\cong K_4$ but in hints, they consider that $L$ is a splitting field of $x^8-1$ and this I see but why do we need this? And not sure what else to do.

$\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a primitive 8th root of unity, does that help you?

An extension $K\subset L$ is galois iff it is normal and separable. It suffices to show that L is a splitting field of some polynomial $f\in K[X]$ to proof that it is normal. You could take $f=x^8-1$ or $f=x^4+1$. It does not matter in this case just which one is more convenient.

@muhammedgunes so essentially the way I did it is also correct?

@strugglingmathguy yes, but as Daniel has said it is good to know that $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$ is a primitve 8th root. It immediately follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$ and this is a cyclotomic extension which is Galois by the way and has degree $\phi(8)=4$. By noting this we see $\zeta_8^2=i$ and so $i,\sqrt{2}\in L$ and L contains 2 subfields of degree 2. This means the Galois group can not be cyclic and must be isomorphic to the 4-group of Klein. From here on you can find all intermediate fields. Just use the fact that the four group has 3 distinct subgroups.
